# How to display lastest post date in the homepage?

Tags: query, date

I'm looking forward to display, somewhere in the homepage of a WP site, a legend saying:

> **Last updated:** XX/XX

by grabbing the date from the most recent post, but not showing any of its content, just the date.

Is there any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would save an option on post save:

```
add_action(
  'save_post',
  function($id,$p) {
    if (
      (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
      || (defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)
      || ($p->post_status === 'auto-draft')
    ) {
      return;
    }
    update_option('_last_site_update',$p->post_date);
  },
  1,2
);
```

And retrieve it with a variant of the function provided by @G-M :

```
function my_last_updated( $format = '' ) {
  $last = get_option('_last_site_update');
  if ( empty($last) ) return;
  if ( empty($format) ) {
    $format = get_option('date_format');
  }
  return mysql2date($format,$last);
}
echo my_last_updated();
```

This way you:

1. push the heavy lifting to the admin side,
2. eliminate the unnecessary work of a full post query ([via
   `wp_get_recent_posts`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L2629)),
3. replace that heavy query with [a very simple `get_option` query](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/option.php#L61),
4. and make the whole thing cache-friendly

Comment: +1 I've started answer saying _"There are different way to do this"_ and this one is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

There are different way to do this.

The easiest, in my opinion is to use `wp_get_recent_posts` to retrieve the last post and the print the post modified date.

Wrapping it in a function make it flexible and reusable. In your `functions.php` you can put:

```
function my_last_updated( $format = '' ) {
  $lasts = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts'=>1, 'post_status'=>'publish') );
  if ( empty($lasts) ) return;
  $last = array_pop($lasts);
  if ( empty($format) ) $format = get_option('date_format');
  return mysql2date( $format, $last['post_modified'] );
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
<p>Last updated: <?php echo my_last_updated() ?>.</p>
```

The argument `$format` let you choose a different date format for the date see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to choose one. If nothing is passed, the format set in WP options is used.

Comment: @RogerW. Yes it works, but answer you accepted is better, I've +1 it. So you have done right choice ;)