# How display modified date of most recent modified post in wordpress?

Tags: date

I need display last modified date of most recent modified post in out of loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you want to display the date - front end or back end? On what page/archive/content type?

Comment: If you haven't seen the [top related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122806/how-to-display-lastest-post-date-in-the-homepage?rq=1) then there's a nice answer there too, saving the last modified date in options.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Place this in your `functions.php` file:

```
function prefix_last_modified_date() { 
  $last_modified_date = null;

  $args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'post', // could be page, or a CPT
    'orderby'    => 'modified',
    'post_count' => 1,
  );

  $last_modified = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ( $last_modified->have_posts() ) {
    $last_modified->the_post();
    $last_modified_date = get_the_modified_date();
  }

  wp_reset_postdata(); 

  return $last_modified_date;
}
```

Then you can display the last modified post date anywhere in your theme:

`echo prefix_last_modified_date();`